# Why this method inherits from class

Tags: c#

```
public Racer(int id, string firstName, string lastName, string country) 
       :this(id, firstName, lastName, country, wins: 0)
{     }
```

Why this

```
(id, firstName, lastName, country, wins: 0)
```

used what is the purpose

And what is the diffent between:

```
public Racer(int id, string firstName, string lastName, string country)
    :this(id, firstName, lastName, country, wins: 0) { }
```

And:

```
public Racer(int id, string firstName, string lastName, string country, int wins)
{
    this.Id = id;
    this.FirstName = firstName;
    this.LastName = lastName;
    this.Country = country;
    this.Wins = wins;
}
```

Comment: First that is a special method, a ctor. Second, it's calling it's base classes constructor and passing required values,with `wins` having a value of 0

Comment: as you can see, the `class` keyword is missing. This is not a class, it is a constructor. And `this` refers to the instance of the class.

Comment: Then what is it-  public Racer(int id, string firstName, string lastName,
string country)
:this(id, firstName, lastName, country, wins: 0)
{ }
public Racer(int id, string firstName, string lastName,
string country, int wins)
{
this.Id = id;
this.FirstName = firstName;
this.LastName = lastName;
this.Country = country;
this.Wins = wins;
}

Comment: @SambitSahoo answered and elaborated..

Answer (score 0):

As what you have seen and posted:

```
public Racer(int id, string firstName, string lastName, string country) 
  :this(id, firstName, lastName, country, wins: 0) 
{ 
} 

public Racer(int id, string firstName, string lastName, string country, int wins) 
{ 
    this.Id = id; 
    this.FirstName = firstName; 
    this.LastName = lastName; 
    this.Country = country; 
    this.Wins = wins; 
}
```

This simply means that you have a `Racer` class and what you have above are two overloaded `constructors` of the `Racer` class. Note that the first constructor does not have `int wins` but the second one does have `int wins` as its last argument.

`this` refers to the instance of the `Racer` `class`. Thus, you can create an instance of the `Racer` `class` in one of the two above ways (save default constructor) like this:

```
Racer racer1 = new Racer(1, "first", "last", "country"); //taking the first constructor

//or

Racer racer1 = new Racer(1, "first", "last", "country", 5); //taking the second constructor
```

Now, when you use the first `constructor` to create the instance of the `class` (and this is what you asked):

```
public Racer(int id, string firstName, string lastName, string country) 
  :this(id, firstName, lastName, country, wins: 0) 
{ 
}
```

It simply means

> "when you want to create a class instance with this constructor
>   without specifying the `wins`, use the second constructor to create it
>   by specifying wins = 0".

Or, in other words, the first `constructor` uses the second `constructor` to create the instance of the `Racer` `class`.

That is, to represent what happen internally, it is as if you change:

```
Racer racer1 = new Racer(1, "first", "last", "country"); //you create by the first constructor
```

into

```
//But internally it uses the second constructor with wins=0
Racer racer1 = new Racer(1, "first", "last", "country", 0); //note the zero
```

Again, it is a `constructor` which calls another `constructor` initialization to create new instance of the `class`. And the `this` simply refers to the instance of the `class` `Racer` which is currently constructed.

Why do we use that? **To save us from some coding**! If we do not have `constructor` which can use another `constructor` to create the instance of the `class` like this:

```
public Racer(int id, string firstName, string lastName, string country) 
  :this(id, firstName, lastName, country, wins: 0) 
{ 
}
```

Then when we want to create `overloaded constructor`, we *cannot* make use of other `constructor` and we have to do it like this:

```
public Racer(int id, string firstName, string lastName, string country) 
{ 
    this.Id = id; 
    this.FirstName = firstName; 
    this.LastName = lastName; 
    this.Country = country; 
    this.Wins = 0; //note the zero, and the above four lines are identical with the other constructor.
}
```

Which seems to be redundant.

Answer (score 0):

This is called constructor chaining.

`C#` allows calling another constructor from called constructor using [`this(...)`](http://www.dotnetperls.com/this-constructor) keyword.

Let's take an example (you provided in the comments), the first constructor doesn't take `wins` parameter, so overloaded constructor been called providing default value (`0` in this case).

If an object creation is called with `wins` supplied then second constructor will be called, which has wins parameter.

```
public Racer(int id, string firstName, string lastName, string country) 
    :this(id, firstName, lastName, country, wins: 0) 
{ 

}

public Racer(int id, string firstName, string lastName, string country, int wins) 
{
    this.Id = id; 
    this.FirstName = firstName; 
    this.LastName = lastName; 
    this.Country = country; 
    this.Wins = wins; 
}
```

Benefit of using a constructor is that it guarantees that the object will go through a proper initialization before an object being used, means we can pre-initialize some of the class variables with values before an object being used.